# Dealing with ArrayOfAnyType (Java) with Axis2

Tags: java, wsdl, apache-axis

I have generated a stub (.java) using Axis2's WSDL2Java application, but I can't deal with the "ArrayOfAnyType" type.

I want to invoke a method that has ArrayOfAnyType as parameter type.

But... how to do that? I have difficultes understanding that class and how to use it.

What I'd rather like to use is a simple Object[]... any explainations on how ArrayOfAnyType works? Thanks!

Comment: What does the signature of the generated code look like?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure which code you mean. I want to use this generated method: connect.setValues(ArrayOfAnyType). I'd rather pass an Object[] instead of the ArrayOfAnyType. I want to use that method to pass several values to login to some service. Thanks for helping! Of course I can create an object of that kind... but how to continue then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are required to use axis, i would urge you to check out jaxws (built into the jdk these days).  it is a lot more straightforward to use in many ways compared to axis.

Comment: I didn't know that was possible. The ArrayOfAnyType class generated by wsimport is much better. (I can simply add Object(s)). Yay! Thanks!